# Is there a way to put a client side generated file in the browser's cache?

Tags: local-storage, browser-cache

This is kind of a shot-in-the-dark question, but I'm going to ask it anyway -- to satisfy my curiosity.

Is there a way to put a client-side generated file in the browser's cache?  Let's say for instance that I want to create a little json.txt file of the user's selections, and next time the page is loaded I can perhaps do an ajax get that would produces the file from cache?  I'm trying to avoid HTML local storage for the time being only because I may want to use that for something else.

Edit:
I missed one point: let's assume I need to store something like 400kb from this file generated on the client -- yes I know this is a lot for "user's selections".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 can do this in some browsers, you can read about it here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Google also tried something like this as well called Gears but have abandoned the project for the native HTML5 versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could store it in a cookie

Comment: Yeah -- I missed that point.  I might want to store more than 4kb.  So, I added a point and exaggerated the size of the thing I might want to store to 400kb.  If I could store that much it would suite my purposes well.